# Spring Boot 3.2.2 with tomcat-embed-core:11.0.0-M17

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, tomcat, spring-boot-3

I need to update the version of tomcat-embed-core because it has vulnerabilities. But I have a problem that in versions 11.0.0-M6 and above, the `setRejectIllegalHeader` function in the `AbstractHttp11Protocol` class has been deprecated, but it is still called in the `TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer` class. That makes the application unable to start with this description.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer.lambda$customizeRejectIllegalHeader$20(TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer.java:209)

The following method did not exist:

    'void org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.setRejectIllegalHeader(boolean)'

The calling method's class, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer, was loaded from the following location:

    jar:file:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/3.2.3/59db74eb4196885bb5a149417ab1ab51dc9b6952/spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.3.jar!/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/embedded/TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer.class

The called method's class, org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/11.0.0-M17/d3818654cd6bf4241e9ade24531727a214a5b18f/tomcat-embed-core-11.0.0-M17.jar!/org/apache/coyote/http11/AbstractHttp11Protocol.class
    jar:file:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-coyote/11.0.0-M17/9101e5a5f564483d13b5cb0bfeb1f042c22a014b/tomcat-coyote-11.0.0-M17.jar!/org/apache/coyote/http11/AbstractHttp11Protocol.class

The called method's class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol: file:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/11.0.0-M17/d3818654cd6bf4241e9ade24531727a214a5b18f/tomcat-embed-core-11.0.0-M17.jar
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol: file:/Users/XXXXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/11.0.0-M17/d3818654cd6bf4241e9ade24531727a214a5b18f/tomcat-embed-core-11.0.0-M17.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains compatible versions of the classes org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer and org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol
```

This is my build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.2.2"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.4"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.22"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.9.22"
    kotlin("plugin.jpa") version "1.9.22"
}

group = "com.company"

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_21
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis") { exclude(group = "io.lettuce", module = "lettuce-core") }
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("com.amazon.ion:ion-java:1.11.0")
    implementation("com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sts:1.12.636") { exclude(group = "software.amazon.ion", module = "ion-java") }
    implementation("com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-secretsmanager:1.12.636") { exclude(group = "software.amazon.ion", module = "ion-java") }
    implementation("org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:11.0.0-M16")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql:42.7.2")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs += "-Xjsr305=strict"
        jvmTarget = "21"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I use Spring Boot 3.2.2, Java 21

In order to be able to run the application, does it need to do anything additional?

Comment: Spring Boot does not yet support Tomcat 11. Is there a reason why you can't use the latest 10.1.x release of Tomcat instead?